# Using Regex to replace standalone characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace `&`  by `&amp;` in only those instances of my input string where `&` is standalone and not followed by `amp;` .
For example:

1.If input is

```
"123&4567&amp;"
```

Output after replace should be:

```
"123&amp;4567&amp;"
```

2.If input is

```
"123&45&67&amp;"
```

Output after replace should be:

```
"123&amp;45&amp;67&amp;"
```

How do I achieve this using C#/Regex?

Thanks.

Comment: replace "&" by "&" ? I guess some things were escaped you didn't want to. Put these things into a code tag :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead. In C# Regex, if I'm not mistaken it would be :

```
&(?!amp;)
```

This will match an & NOT followed by 'amp;'

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to replace &amp; with & then replace all &'s with &amp; thereby avoiding any weird regex solution

To clarify: I realize he was asking for examples in regex I just think he can get it done using an easier to understand str replace function rather than a regex solution.

```
// in javascript
var str = "Test string & & &amp; & TEST";
str = str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&'); // "Test string & & & & TEST"
str = str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;'); // "Test string &amp; &amp; &amp; &amp; TEST"
console.log(str);
```

Doing it this way makes it easier for the intern to understand your code and all you sacrifice is being a bit clever.

And yes I know that uses regex but just barely ;)